# Get all text from all divs with the same class name in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get all today's big games from [Bet365](https://www.bet365.es/#/HO/) (Warning its a gambling site!) but i only can get one which is the first game.

I try this but no working:

```
try:
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://www.bet365.es/#/HO/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
except:
    print("No se ha podido acceder a Bet365. Comprueba si la página funciona correctamente y no estas bloqueado de ella.")
try:
    partidos_destacados = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fh-ParticipantFixtureTeam_TruncateName")

    for i in partidos_destacados:
        print(i.text)
except:
    print("No se han podido leer los partidos destacados. Comprueba si ha cambiado el nombre del class en el HTML de BET365")
```

There are many divs with class name "fh-ParticipantFixtureTeam_TruncateName" and I need get all of this.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the error. Im using driver.find_element_by_class_name but i need use driver.find_elements_by_class_name.

This is the code fixed:

```
try:
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://www.bet365.es/#/HO/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
except:
    print("No se ha podido acceder a Bet365. Comprueba si la página funciona correctamente y no estas bloqueado de ella.")
try:
    partidos_destacados = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fh-ParticipantFixtureTeam_TruncateName")

    for i in partidos_destacados:
        print(i.text)
except:
    print("No se han podido leer los partidos destacados. Comprueba si ha cambiado el nombre del class en el HTML de BET365")
```